# Using Android Parcelable with nested objects?

Tags: java, android, serialization, parcelable

I have a class that I have implemented Parcelable. In that class I am using a list of objects from a jar. I was wondering how I can write that List without being able to implement parcelable on the someObject. Currently my class seems to writeToParcel fine it is when I am reading it back in that I am having issues.  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: check this complete example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400564/android-parcelable-retailerorderactivity-java-return-null/7400675#7400675

Comment: That is a nice example but I cannot modify the class in my ArrayList so I can implement Parcelable on that class.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not that big of a deal, you could (if the JAR's class implements Serializable) call [writeSerializable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeSerializable%28java.io.Serializable%29) on the `Parcel`.

Comment: That would be perfect but the class does not implement Serializable.

Comment: Then perhaps serialize what you want from the class and create a new one (with that data) when de-serializing?