# how to pass complex Library class object from one activity to another activity

Tags: android

I need to pass an object from one activity to another activity ,
I am using tesserect OCr Library so I need to pass its object,Please tell me how i do this i am struck here.
Advance Thanks.

Comment: You can go with a solution either from `Parcelable` or `Serilizable`.

Comment: Look here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846162/best-way-to-pass-objects-from-one-activity-to-another

Answer (score 0):

For either parcelable/serializable, you are required to know its internal structure. If you don't know it or cannot guess it, then I suggest you make it a global object and access it from whichever activity you require.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with a solution either from Parcelable or Serializable

**Using Serializablee its pretty easy :-**

just make your custom class as Serializable ( by extend Serializable class )

```
intent.putExtra("myobject", new Persion("name1",915698452387));
```

get from target activity :-

```
Person p1 = (Person) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myobject");
```

try this..