# Android Parcelable Implementation with ArrayList<Object>

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist, parcelable

so I am implementing a test app in which I will create a Tournament object as Parcelable and will pass them between intents.
A tournament include:
. A tournament name
. Rule
. Rule for matching players (random/manual)
. An array list of Players

This is what I have so far:

**Tournament.java**

```
public class TournamentData implements Parcelable {
private String tourName;
private int bestOf;
private boolean isRandom;
private ArrayList<Player> playerList;

public TournamentData(String name, int tourBestOf, boolean random) {
    this.tourName = name;
    this.bestOf = tourBestOf;
    this.isRandom = random;
}

public void addPlayer(Player newPlayer) {
    this.playerList.add(newPlayer);
}

public ArrayList<Player> getPlayerList() {
    return playerList; 
}

    /* getters and setters excluded from code here */

    public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

**Player.java**

```
public class Player {

private String playerName;
private String playerEmail;

public Player(String name, String email) {
    this.playerName = name;
    this.playerEmail = email;
}
    /* getter and setters are excluded */
```

}

I am new to Android (i mean very very new; 10 hours into it I guess). So I am wondering:
. Is it possible to create a Parcelable object given the specs of Tournament object that has ArrayList?
. How to store all the tournament data into a Parcelable object and access them from the other activity? (namely A and B).

Comment: checkout this answer which has complete example for how to parse arrayList using Parcelable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400564/android-parcelable-retailerorderactivity-java-return-null/7400675#7400675

Comment: @LalitPoptani: So does the player object have to be Parcelable as well?

Comment: @LalitPoptani: Thx to your help. I have finished implementing the parcelable objects! I will add the code I implemented soon so that other people can refer to it when they bump into the same issue!

Comment: If you want than I should answer my link in here then you can upvote and check mark it. :)

Comment: Ok Thanks I had posted my answer. :)

Comment: "will pass them between intents" ????

Comment: Try this tool, it's very useful: http://devk.it/proj/parcelabler/

Answer (score 2):

here is code that show you how parcle a arraylist

```
public class ParcleListTopic implements Parcelable{
    private List<ParcleTopic> list;
    private ArrayList<HoldListTopic> listh=new ArrayList<HoldListTopic>();
    public ArrayList<HoldListTopic> GetListTopic()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            listh.add(list.get(i).GetHold());
        }
        return listh;
    }
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeTypedList(list);
    }
    public ParcleListTopic(Parcel in)
    {
        in.readTypedList(list,ParcleTopic.CREATOR);

    }
    public ParcleListTopic(List<ParcleTopic> list)
    {
        this.list=list;
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcleListTopic> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ParcleListTopic>(){
          public ParcleListTopic createFromParcel(Parcel s)
          {
              return new ParcleListTopic(s);
          }
          public ParcleListTopic[] newArray(int size) 
          {
                return new ParcleListTopic[size];
          }
    };
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}


public class ParcleTopic implements Parcelable
{
    HoldListTopic hold;
    public ParcleTopic(HoldListTopic hold)
    {
        this.hold=hold;
    }
    public HoldListTopic GetHold()
    {
        return hold;
    }
    public int describeContents() 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeString(hold.Title);
        dest.writeString(hold.Date);
        dest.writeInt(hold.NumberComment);
        dest.writeInt(hold.ID);
    }
    public ParcleTopic(Parcel in)
    {
        hold.Title=in.readString();
        hold.Date=in.readString();
        hold.NumberComment=in.readInt();
        hold.ID=in.readInt();
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcleTopic> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ParcleTopic>()
    {
          public ParcleTopic createFromParcel(Parcel s)
          {
              return new ParcleTopic(s);
          }
          public ParcleTopic[] newArray(int size) 
          {
                return new ParcleTopic[size];
          }
    }; }
```

Answer (score 0):

a lot of these things turn out to be R.P.C.'s -- I would write the major portion of the work in traditional Java then try to make the ......

yep, sure enough:

> Container for a message (data and object references) that can be sent through an IBinder. A Parcel can contain both flattened data that will be unflattened on the other side of the IPC (using the various methods here for writing specific types, or the general Parcelable interface), and references to live IBinder objects that will result in the other side receiving a proxy IBinder connected with the original IBinder in the Parcel.

in other words Parcel is a form of interprocess communication ....

you have to re-think the base model as this is not a 10,000 requests a second server - what it is is a hand-held consumer device that can just pull the pointers off the process table if it has to because of where it operates

I have learned to go to the blog tab at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/?hl=en

be very careful not to drill the entry deep into stuff that needs to be in worker threads and note the rich synchronization primitives that Java makes easy to use

> Multithreading For Performance

Posted by Tim Bray on 19 July 2010 at 11:41 AM
[This post is by Gilles Debunne, an engineer in the Android group who loves to get multitasked. — Tim Bray]

it's in the blogs --- much better place to start