# Passing a ListAdapter in bundle

Tags: android

I am working on handling the change of screen orientation. In my onSaveInstanceState() method, I wanted to pass the ListAdapter itself in, and then read it back out in onCreate(). Is this the best way to handle an orientation change, or do I have to pass an ArrayList of all the objects in the listadapter, and use it to repopulate the listAdapter in onCreate()?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code in activity tag in manifest file

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

or you should pass a arraylist from your objects in the listadapter  and for passing arraylist you should parcle it .see my code here [Android Parcelable Implementation with ArrayList<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192984/android-parcelable-implementation-with-arraylistobject/17254541#17254541)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save ListView, you just had to store the data with which you are populating your ListView.

1- [Here is the example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/09/onsaveinstancestate-and.html)

2- [Here is another example](http://alltechsolution.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/savedinstance-onsaveinstancestate-onrestoreinstancestate/)

I hope this will help you out surely.

Thanks