# Android Parcelable create array

Tags: android, parcelable

In background i parse JSON, and then in this background i send Json to parcelable 
And in Parcelable i `writestring` with `JSONObject.optString` how i can write ArrayList?

```
List<Row> result = new ArrayList<Row>(array.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    result.add(new Row(array.optJSONObject(i)));
                }
```

Parcelable.java

```
public Row(JSONObject from) {
        thumb = from.optString(TAG_THUMBNAILS);
        bigImage = from.optString(TAG_BIG_IMAGE);
        author = from.optString(TAG_AUTHOR);
        description = from.optString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
        date = from.optString(TAG_DATE);
    }

    public Row(Parcel parcel) {
        thumb = parcel.readString();
        bigImage = parcel.readString();
        author = parcel.readString();
        description = parcel.readString();
        date = parcel.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeString(thumb);
        parcel.writeString(bigImage);
        parcel.writeString(author);
        parcel.writeString(description);
        parcel.writeString(date);
    }
```

Comment: chek this,[ArrayList with Parcelable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400564/android-parcelable-retailerorderactivity-java-return-null/7400675#7400675)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not complete but I think you will get the point. Will try to assist you.

```
public class Row implements Parceleable{

    private String thumb;
    private String bigImage;
   private String author;
    private String description;
    private String date;

// your setters and getters here
    public void setThumb(String thumb){
        this.thumb = thumb;
    }
    public String getThumb(){
        return thumb;
    }
// ....

    public Row(){
     } 

    public Row(Parcel parcel) {
        thumb = parcel.readString();
        bigImage = parcel.readString();
        author = parcel.readString();
        description = parcel.readString();
        date = parcel.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeString(thumb);
        parcel.writeString(bigImage);
        parcel.writeString(author);
        parcel.writeString(description);
        parcel.writeString(date);
    }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<Row> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {

    @Override
    public Row createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Row(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Row[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Row[size];
    }
  };
}
```

Populate from your json:

```
List<Row> myRowArray = new ArrayList<Row>;

Row result;
           for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                result = new Row();
                result.setThumb( fromJson ); //Set thumb string you got from json
                result.setAuthor( fromJson ); //Set Author string you got from json
                 .....
                 myRowArray.add(result);
            }
```

That's how we do it.It is very easy. At the beginning it is little confusing but if you learn the point you will find out it is easy and very handy.