# How to read a List of Parceable Objects

Tags: android

I have a object A that contain an List of Object B's. Now i wish to place the object A into a Bundle by using a Parceable bundle. How can i do this ?

```
Class A{
 ArrayList<B> secondClass
}
class B{
}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7400675/726863

Comment: duplicate of ... (why this appears here ... this only increases the laziness of those who ask such questions) ... it should be "duplicate - use seaerch option"

Answer (score 0):

Parceable Interface for classes whose instances can be written to and restored from a Parcel. Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also have a static field called CREATOR, which is an object implementing the Parcelable.Creator interface.

So You need to implements `Parcelable` in Class A

For details See [this link](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html)