# How to write and read ArrayList<String> to parcel in android

Tags: android

In my project, I have to write and read `ArrayList<String>` to parcel, I tried with writeList and writeStringList but no use, I am getting exceptions while reading the lists.

Could any one help me in this?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Hi

Your question is not clear but if you want to read/write an ArrayList<String>
here's a way

To read an ArrayList<String> you need a for each loop 
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
for(String str: list){
//do something here with the str 
}

Comment: Post some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Post your code and logcat details .check this http://idlesun.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-parcelable-example-2-subobject.html

Comment: Need more detail in this question. `writeStringList`, `readStringList` and `createStringArrayList` are the methods you probably want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7400675/726863

Answer (score 8):

By @JeremyRoman: `writeStringList`, `readStringList` and `createStringArrayList` all exist on `Parcel` since API 1.

Comment: `writeStringList`, `readStringList` and `createStringArrayList` all exist on [`Parcel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) since API 1.

Comment: @JeremyRoman Correct. I might need a good sleep before continuing to answer questions. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @HinataHyuga I edited my answer. My previous answer was incorrect. Check revisions so you know. Thanks.

Comment: @StoneBird Put answer in your post not in your comment.

Comment: @HinataHyuga That's not my answer.

Comment: @StoneBird Whatever is your correct answer. Edit your post and put correct answer there.

Comment: Hi thanks everybody,I used writeStringList for writing to stringlist to parcel and while reading I forgot to intialise the arraylist object to while the read value to assign

Comment: Please correct your answer. Or atleast provide steps to use the said methods. Else delete the answer and add it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

use this to write:

```
bundle.putStringArrayList(KEY, stringArrayList);
```

and this to read:

```
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = bundle.getStringArrayList(KEY);
```