# Passing ArrayList<CustomObject> Between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist, parcelable

i've implemented a Parcelable class:

```
public class Evento implements Parcelable {
    private int;
    private String ;
    private String imagen;
    //more atts

    //Constructors, setters and getters

public Evento(Parcel in) {
    this.id = in.readInt();
    this.titulo = in.readString();
    this.imagen=in.readString();

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {     
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(titulo);
    dest.writeString(imagen);       
}
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Evento> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Evento>() {
    @Override
    public Evento createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Evento(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Evento[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Evento[size];
    }
};
```

In my activity, i'm trying to pass an arrayList to an other activitie:
I'me overwriten onItemClick and i'm passing the information this way:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            //create new activitie
            ArrayList<Eventos> eventos = new ArrayList<Eventos>();
            Intent intent = new Intent(QueActivity.this, ProductosCategorias.class);

            //Create information
            Bundle informacion= new Bundle();
            informacion.putParcelableArrayList("eventos", eventos);
            intent.putExtras(informacion);
```

and receiving it in the other activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_productos_categorias);     
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaCategoriaElegida);
    Bundle informacionRecibida = getIntent().getExtras();               
    ArrayList<Evento> eventos =new ArrayList<Evento>();
    eventos= informacionRecibida.getParcelableArrayList("eventos");
```

I'm getting a null pointer exception. I've debbuged it and i'm getting NULL when i execute the getParcelableArrayList("eventos"), i mean, my arraylist eventos is null, so, i'm receiving no information.

Any help will be great

Comment: you have to put the bundle in the intent.

Comment: also this code `informacion.putParcelableArrayList("eventos", ArrayList<Eventos> eventos);` does not even compile, so I don't assume this is the actual code you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass object from one activity to another in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Comment: It's not the actual code i'm using. I've already put the bundle in the intent. @Sameer post is not duplicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7400675/726863

Comment: see this tutorial http://xtreamcoder.com/pass-custom-arraylist/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code

```
Bundle informacion= new Bundle();
informacion.putParcelableArrayList("eventos", ArrayList<Eventos> eventos);
intent.putExtras(informacion);
```

Should be

```
Bundle informacion = new Bundle();
ArrayList<Eventos> mas = new ArrayList<Eventos>();
informacion.putSerializable("eventos", mas);
intent.putExtras(informacion);
```

and Make sure your Eventos structure like a serializable object

```
private class Eventos implements Serializable {

}
```

**Reading Values**

```
ArrayList<Eventos> madd=getIntent().getSerializableExtra(key);
```

Comment: He asked about parcelable and you answered with serializable, you actually didn't solve the problem with his code but suggested something completely different which much less efficient.

Comment: I second @TOMKA . Please fix your answer

Comment: Serializable has very poor performance in Android. Use Parcelable.

Answer (score 1):

Parcelable is much better than serialization in a performance wise and other features.

refer this link:

http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development