# Android - Retrieve Selected Items in a CheckBox

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve the selected item from a list to be added to the user's List.

The user would select the project that would be added to the user in a different activity then return to main activity with the newly added projects to the list.

The functionality of adding should be done when the user select multiple or single item from the list when the use click on the floating button presented in the activity.

**Activity**

```
    public class ProjectSelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<Project> Projects;
    private Player Player;
    private ProjectSelectionAdapter Adapter;
    private ListView ProjectSelectionLV;
    private FloatingActionButton AddProject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_project_selection);


        AddProject = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.ProjectSelectionFloatingActionButton);

        Player = (Player)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Player");
        Projects = (ArrayList<Project>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Projects");
        Adapter = new ProjectSelectionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Projects);

        ProjectSelectionLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ProjectSelectionListView);
        ProjectSelectionLV.setAdapter(Adapter);

        AddProject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
 }
```

**Adapter:**

```
    public class ProjectSelectionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Project> projects;
    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    private View view;

    public ProjectSelectionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Project> projects) {
        this.context = context;
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return projects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return projects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        inflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView == null){
            view = new View(context);
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.project_selection_view, null);

            TextView Title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ProjectSelectionTitleTextView);
            TextView Value = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ProjectSelectionValueTextView);
            TextView Revenue = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ProjectSelectionRevenueTextView);
            ImageView Image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ProjectSelectionImage);

            Title.setText(projects.get(position).getTitle());
            Value.setText("التكلفة: " + Integer.toString(projects.get(position).getValue()));
            Revenue.setText("الربح: " + Integer.toString(projects.get(position).getRevenue()));
            Image.setImageResource(projects.get(position).getImage());
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Item view**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProjectSelectionTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ProjectSelectionImage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ProjectSelectionImage"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/farm_fruit"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ProjectSelectionCheckbox"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ProjectSelectionCheckbox" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProjectSelectionValueTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Value"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ProjectSelectionRevenueTextView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ProjectSelectionImage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProjectSelectionRevenueTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Revenue"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ProjectSelectionImage"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ProjectSelectionImage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ProjectSelectionCheckbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ProjectSelectionValueTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ProjectSelectionValueTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make another `Arraylist` which will store all the selected projects in your activity.

   ```
   private ArrayList<Project> selectedProjects;
   ```

2.You can add onItemClickListener() on your Listview like this -

```
ProjectSelectionLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               //inside this check if your checkbox corresponding to this item is selected or not. You can do this by taking checkbox from **parent** which you are getting in this method and checking if this checkbox is selected or not. 
              //If the checkbox is selected, then add the project of this position to your selectedProjects ArrayList -
              //selectedProjects.add(Projects.get(position));
              //Make sure to check that selectedProjects does not contain this already to avoid duplicates
            }
        });
```

3. When user clicks the floating button, inside its onClick() method, you can pass the `selectedProjects` ArrayList using `intent extras`. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942179/passing-arraylistcustomobject-between-activities) to see how to pass objects between activities.
4. Finally, in your other activity, use `selectedProjects` Arraylist to add new projects. Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when you have added the new projects from `selectedProjects`.

**EDIT** - To get the checkbox in 2nd step, you can do -

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) rl.getChildAt(4);
```

Comment: Great! One more question, how can I access the checkbox value from the view passed onItemClickListener?

Comment: I've tried if( ((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.ProjectSelectionCheckbox)).isChecked() ){
                    SelectedProjects.add(Projects.get(position));
                }

Comment: I think you have to use parent argument. Let me make an edit

Comment: I'm getting NullException on the SelectedProject list. I've added the code to to the Listview listener RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) rl.getChildAt(position);
                if(cb.isChecked()){
                    if(!SelectedProjects.contains(Projects.get(position))){
                        SelectedProjects.add(Projects.get(position));
                    }
                }

Comment: You have to initialise the list before using it - selectedProjects = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: For testing I'm displaying a toast with the size of the selectedproject and it's showing me 0

Comment: Yes, but the list of selectedprojects isn't updating with the selected project from the list.

Comment: You will have to debug it as I can't seem to locate the problem :). Try putting log statements inside your if(cb.isChecked()) and other locations. Identify where it's going wrong. I will be able to help you then :)

Comment: I've added a toast under the isChecked statement to be fired when the user check on the item but it seems the code is unreachable.

Comment: Great !! Can you add cb.performClick(); before this "if condition". Also, if it doesn't work, try our previous approach where we used view.findViewByID()

Comment: No luck with both approaches.

Comment: Ahh !! I guess then you have to change the approach. I did this with recycler view long back and it worked. Try this - http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html It is exactly what you want. If you get stuck anywhere, ping me. Thanks

Comment: Step 3 and 4 will remain same :)

Comment: Great I was able to implement the checkbox through the tutorial you have submitted but I had to add a condition to solve a IndexOutOfBound at the position. I will post the solution to include the adding of project to the player.

Comment: @NasserX My answer is according to your question. Since your further problems were out of the scope of this question, I followed the discussion in comments. Please accept the answer since it is the answer to your question. You can raise another question for "One more question, how can I access the checkbox value from the view passed onItemClickListener?" and answer it yourself so that it is helpful for the community. Thanks :-)