# Pass through Parcelable List<?> through bundle of activity

Tags: android, list, fragment, parcelable

How to pass through Parcelable, an object of type List  In the fragment through the Bundle of Activity?
Constantly produces an error type NPE, In the preparation Parcelable in OnCreateView.

```
// Fragment object в Activity
public Fragment systemFragList(){
          a = new AppsManagerFragment();
          b = new Bundle();
          dApps = new DataApps(this);
          //transmission through List the designer
          listCreater = new MakingListObject(dApps.getSystemAppsList()); 
          b.putParcelable("List", listCreater); // transfer Parcelable object through Bundle
          a.setArguments(b);

        return a;
    };

// Parcelable class
public class MakingListObject implements Parcelable {

    private List<ApplicationInfo> list;

 // get an object List <ApplicationInfo> constructor
    public MakingListObject(List<ApplicationInfo> l) { 
        this.list = l;
    }
    public MakingListObject(Parcel in) {
        in.readTypedList(list, ApplicationInfo.CREATOR); // read
    }
    public List<ApplicationInfo> getList(){ // vethod return list
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) { // write
       dest.writeTypedList(list);
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

   CREATOR...
}

//Admission List to the Fragment in onCreateView()    
MakingListObject obj = (MakingListObject)this.getArguments().getParcelable("List"); // NPE ERROR
List<ApplicationInfo> listData = obj.getList();
```

Comment: Please try to phrase your question more clearly, it's pretty hard to understand what you need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7400675/726863

Comment: Emil, Arises NPE error getting Parcelable in OnCreteView.

Answer (score 3):

store list of `Parcelable` using

```
Bundle dataToSend = new Bundle();
ArrayList<? super Parcelable> list = new ArrayList<>();

//add items here
```

and read it using

```
Bundle receivedData = ...
receivedData.getParcelableArrayList("foo")
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to init the list first.

```
public MakingListObject(Parcel in) {
    list = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>;
    in.readTypedList(list, ApplicationInfo.CREATOR); // read
}
```

Comment: The code can be seen that the constructor initializes the list. Though so I also tried and still there NPE.